# Simple HTML / CSS Questions - Height & Screen Resolution

Tags: html, css, height, screen, screen-resolution

I need to make a div have a certain height, it has a repeating image in it and I want it to take up the entire screen no matter what the users screen resolution is. Height auto depends on the content so do I need to use javascript in order to achieve my goal? Or can I use something with a "clear:both;" property on it in order to always stretch the div to the bottom? I would really like to avoid javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as the parent container (like `body` or `html`) has `100% height`, then the `div` should also.  So

```
html, body{
    height:100%;
}
div{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/Jm8Mt/

*Of course, your `div` would have a `class`... example was just for show*

Answer (score 0):

Giving the div 100% height and width will make it take up the entire of the window.

```
#fullscreen {
height:100%;
width:100%;
}
```